# Azure Functions: Why is Visual Studio 2022 Missing Functions worker options?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

I'm trying to follow a [QuickStart Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio) for C# functions in Azure using Visual Studio 2022, and I seem to be missing some options when I try to select my "Functions worker". According to the tutorial, I should have an option for ".NET 6.0 Isolated (Long Term Support)", but it is not showing up in the list.

Why am I missing this option, and how can I fix the issue?

[Picture of the Available Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp4e6.png)

I've run through the Visual Studio 2022 Installer several times, and have made sure to select "Azure Development", along with all the optional components. I've also added the ".NET 6.0 Runtime (Long Term Support)" individual component. Still no luck.

Comment: _".NET Framework v1"_ What!!!!! Something is definitely wrong.

Comment: @Greg What version of VS 2022 you are using?[image](https://i.imgur.com/SQITV9w.png)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else ever comes across this post, it ended up being a [firewall issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-and-use-visual-studio-behind-a-firewall-or-proxy-server).

Comment: What firewall settings did you change?  I'm having the same issue with VS2022 on my personal machine and its already added as a firewall exception.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @user501211 I'm behind a corporate firewall, and I didn't actually change anything in the firewall; I just came across this article and it sparked the idea that it might be a firewall issue. I uninstalled VS2022 entirely, and then connected to an unrestricted wireless router, and reinstalled VS2022 while connect to that. After reinstalling I created a new project while connected to the wifi, and all was working as expected. After moving back to the corporate firewall, things continue to work.. at least for now.

Comment: Mine was something unrelated to firewalls but eventually figured it out.  After uninstalling and re-installing VS2022 multiple times I found another suggestion of deleting the `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools` folder.

Apparently doing this forces Visual Studio to re-create it, and when it did that it successfully was able to target the correct versions of the functions runtime.

Answer (score 0):

user5012211's answer solved it for me. I had already installed
C:\Users<your username>\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools folder. Apparently doing this forces Visual Studio to re-create it, and when it did that it successfully was able to target the correct versions of the functions runtime